# Represent data structures on Form Data when Content-Type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post, xmlhttprequest, axios

I'm trying to recreate the following **Form Data** for POST request to backend **without touching or changing the backend code because I have no information or access to it.**

```
start: 0
limit: 25
search: {"eng_num":"2","cost_center":"1343","uid":"","andOr":[]}
```

So far, I have been using the following code to make post requests:

```
        let formBody = [];
        let form = {
            'start': ...,
            'limit': ...,
        };
        for (let property in form) {
            let encodedKey = encodeURIComponent(property);
            let encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(form[property]);
            formBody.push(encodedKey + "=" + encodedValue);
        }
```

However, when I add the search attribute like this, `search` is displayed as `[Object Object]` under **Chorme > Network > Headers > Form Data**

```
        let form = {
            'start': ...,
            'limit': ...,
            'search': {
                'cost_center': ...,
                'uid': ...,
                'andOr': ...,
                'eng_num': ...,
            }
        };
```

My question is how should change my code so that I achieve

```
search: {"eng_num":"2","cost_center":"1343","uid":"","andOr":[]}
```

format in Form Data.

Relevant parts of the request headers

```
Accept: *
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Comment: The `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format has no standard way to represent data structures that aren't flat key=value pair structures. There are some extensions which allow arrays of strings (notably implemented in Perl's CGI module and a bunch of things that follow its patterns) and other extensions that allow complex data structures  (notably PHP's) but how you express that data depends entirely on what the backend code is doing … and you've told us nothing about that.

Comment: Don't confuse JavaScript with JSON.

Comment: the desired format was achieved previously by a former developer using jquery. I am recreating front-end using react, so there must be a way to get the desired format using javascript? Backend is legacy code and also I do not have access to it, so I was wondering if its possible to solve this issue without touching the backend